# ACF field in child/sub category

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a ACF field in woocommerce sub category field. the field shows up just fine in the wordpress admin but when i try to display the custom field of the child category the parent custom field shows up. how do  i show ACF child categories of wordpress. this is the code im using that displays the parents ACF field:

```php
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);

$term_id = get_queried_object_id($current_category);

echo get_field('designer_name', 'product_cat_' . $term_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per ACF documentation, it should be like this instead of yours:

```
$term = get_queried_object();    
$term_id = $term->term_id; 

echo get_field('designer_name', 'term_' . $term_id);
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

EDIT
The above was reported to get the parent field value, to display the children:

```
$term = get_queried_object();    
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy =  $term->taxonomy;

$children_terms = get_term_children(  $term_id, $taxonomy );

if( !is_wp_error( $children_terms ) && $children_terms ){
    foreach( $children_terms as $child ){
        echo get_field('designer_name', 'term_' . $child );
   }
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/

Comment: This displays the PARENT acf field, I need it to display the child acf field

Comment: OK, thought you were on the child taxonomy page already. Will update my answer.

Comment: hi tammi this almost works thanks, however its displaying the custom fields values for ALL child categories and not the one relevant to that category alone

Comment: @PhilipSavarirayan I should be able to help you display just the correct one, but without access to the site and code it is difficult to guess. Is there any way you can tell me of how to know in the code which term_id or term slug or name is the relevant current category?

Comment: What do you get if you echo get_query_var($taxonomy); @PhilipSavarirayan?